# SQL Statement to Remove Duplicates and get Counts

Tags: sql, ms-access

My continuing SQL headache...

If I run this paraphrased code:

```
SELECT State, Name, ID
FROM ...
WHERE Lost=False
```

I will get something like the following back:

```
State        Name        ID
NY            A          123
NY            A          123
NY            B          234
NY            C          345
MD            X          356
MD            Y          668
```

What I really need is a sum of the number of resources in each state.  The problem here is that If I just do something like the following, it won't take into account that there are clearly duplicates (see the first two records above).

```
 SELECT state, Count(state) AS statecount
    FROM ....
   GROUP BY state, Lost
   HAVING Lost=false
```

How can I get a count of the # of records for each state where lost = false while only pulling distinct records?
I thought maybe putting DISTINCT in the first query and then running a Query of a Query in ColdFusion but you can't do things like aggregates in subqueries.

Basically, using the above as an example, I'd ultimately want this:

```
            State      Count
              NY          3 (not 4!)
              MD          2
```

I should note... this is in Access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Access 2007  supports inline views. so you can do this. (I don't know about earlier versions)

```
SELECT 
   state,
   COUNT(CR_ID )

   FROM

   (


       SELECT  DISTINCT 
       lkuState.StateName AS state, 
       tblMain.CR_ID 
       FROM lkuState 
       INNER JOIN 
       (tblMain 
       INNER JOIN (locLink 
       INNER JOIN tblLoc 
       ON locLink.GEOMETRY_ID = tblLoc.GEOMETRY_ID) 
       ON tblMain.CR_ID = locLink.CR_ID) 
       ON lkuState.FIPS_State = tblLoc.FIPS_State 

       WHERE tblMain.Lost=False) t

GROUP BY
State
```

**Update**

As David-W-Fenton Notes below in regards to my uncertainty about which versions supported derived tables/inline views

> Derived tables have long been supported by Jet/ACE, though the syntax used to be quite different from the simple (SELECT...) As Alias -- it was [SELECT...]. Note the trailing period on the close square bracket, and that this precluded a SQL SELECT where internal square brackets were required

Comment: I get an error:  HAVING clause (tblMain.Lost=0) without grouping or aggregation.

Comment: @stuttsdc Sorry that should have been a where

Comment: I think that's it!  Sweet!  I'll let you know if I'm mistaken but this looks good so far.

Comment: Derived tables have long been supported by Jet/ACE, though the syntax used to be quite different from the simple `(SELECT...) As Alias` -- it was `[SELECT...]. As Alias`. Note the trailing period on the close square bracket, and that this precluded a SQL SELECT where internal square brackets were required. I am unclear in modern versions of Access where and when the () syntax is reliably usable. I'd think it would require SQL 92 mode to be turned on, but I don't believe it does.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton Nice. I wish I had known about this earlier. I've updated my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

First create a view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT State, Name FROM OriginalTable
```

Then, in your larger query, substitute OriginalTable for the table you draw this information from.

Answer (score 0):

First Add an Identity column in your table by using

```
alter table ATTENDANCE add AUTOID INT IDENTITY
```

Then run below query

```
Select State,count(*) as cnt
FROM TableName
WHERE AUTOID IN (SELECT MAX(AUTOID) FROM TableName GROUP BY State, Name, id)
group by State
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a language named "SPL" can do this with one row code:

```js
file("d:/table.xlsx").xlsimport@tx().group(State;~.icount(ID):count)
```

Showing in below attachment :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eola3.png]

Comment: I don't think giving an answer to a fairly specific question in a completely different language is very helpful. Especially since this one seems to be based on Excel files, and spreadsheets and databases aren't really interchangable

Comment: This question didn't limit to mysql or oracle databases, i only show another language  
 maybe easier to discribe a data caculation; if your data come database, change code to :                           
connect("mysqlDB").query("select * from table").group(State;~.icount(ID):count)
                             comes csv file, then                        
file("table.csv").import@t(;",").group(State;~.icount(ID):count)
                 whatever else other kinds datasouce。 my english is poor, sorry:)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT state, Count(distinct ID) AS statecount
FROM ....
GROUP BY state, Lost
HAVING Lost=false
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Don't think that works in Access.   I hoped it would be that simple but I'm getting back a syntax error: missing operator in query expression 'Count(distinct tblMain.CR_ID)'    Here's my query in full:   SELECT lkuState.StateName AS state, Count(distinct tblMain.CR_ID) AS statecount
FROM lkuState INNER JOIN (tblMain INNER JOIN (locLink INNER JOIN tblLoc ON locLink.GEOMETRY_ID = tblLoc.GEOMETRY_ID) ON tblMain.CR_ID = locLink.CR_ID) ON lkuState.FIPS_State = tblLoc.FIPS_State
GROUP BY lkuState.StateName, tblMain.Lost
HAVING (((tblMain.Lost)=False));

Comment: @stutsdc. access does not support count(distint), so look to this approach http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2007/09/19/writing-a-count-distinct-query-in-access.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  But I am having some trouble w/the syntax, unfortunately.  Shouldn't be this maddening...

Comment: You should check that the target SQL dialect supports the command you're suggesting before bothering to post. The other person who posted Count(distinct) has deleted his answer. Seems appropriate here, too.